# Template Literal is Empty When Used Within Single Quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code that works:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${widgetId}_1" id="${widgetId}_1" value="Hello"/>

var result = '$request.getParameter("${widgetId}_data")';
```

However, my template literal seems to go blank if I change it to this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SomeSampleElement" id="SomeSampleElement" value="Hello"/>
<input type="hidden" name="SomeSampleElement_data" id="SomeSampleElement_data" value="ValueData"/>

var element = $jQuery("#SomeSampleElement");
var result = '$request.getParameter("${element.id}_data")';
```

Element is an HTML element in this case.

Comment: Template literals use backticks, not single quotes.

Comment: Single and double quotes make ordinary string literals, not template literals.

Comment: When I do `console.log("${element.id}_data");` it logs the entire string `${element.id}_data`, not just `_data`.

Comment: isn't `SomeSampleElement` trying to match an element with a tag named "SomeSampleElement" ?  Should this not be `[name="SomeSampleElement"]`?

Answer (score 2):

You should use backticks for [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
console.log(`${element.id}_data`);
```

Comment: How about in this case? var result = '$request.getParameter("${element.id}_data")';
That's my biggest issue since I need to grab data from the request.

Comment: @JonathanNguyen It's the same thing -- use backticks instead of double quotes.

Comment: Don't put single quotes around the whole thing. `var result = $request.getParameter(\`${element.id}_data\`);`

Comment: you are saving a string to `result` if you use `'`, get rid of them then.

Comment: @JonathanNguyen Don't try to put this in a comment, backticks have special markup meaning in comments.

Comment: I get this error with your new line:

[ WIDGET ERROR org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Lexical error, Encountered: "`" (96), after : "" at *unset*[line 45, column 44]]

Comment: var result = $request.getParameter(${id}); (backticks at around the ${id}. $request.getParameter returns only string I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Single and double quotes are used for string literals. There's no special meaning of `${...}` inside string literals, it's just taken literally.

Use backticks to make a template literal. Sinxw you're trying to create a function call string, put the entire string inside the backticks. Then put single quotes or double quotes around the argument.

You also need `#` in the first selector to select the sample element.

```
var element = jQuery("#SomeSampleElement")[0];
var result = `$request.getParameter('${element.id}_data')`;
console.log(result);
```

It appears that you're using a 3rd-party template engine that uses `${...}` for its own purposes. SO you should use concatenation instead:

```
var result = '$request.getParameter("' + element.id_data + '")';
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198325/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-template-literal-is-empty-when-used-within-single).